# How to debug what is causing window.confirm to blink repeatedly? (Jquery-ujs)

Tags: javascript

I use `jquery-ujs` with Rails, which allows us to ask for a confirmation before a form submit by using `data-confirm="Confirm submit?"`.

I have this very weird bug on a specific page that the `window.confirm` is blinking very fast as soon as I click on the submit button, like if there was multiple event handlers attached.

This is the HTML code:

```
<button name="button" type="submit" data-confirm="Do you confirm?" data-disable-with="Wait..." class="btn btn-primary">
Submit
</button>
```

And this is what happens when the button is clicked (note the window.confirm appearing for a flash of a second, and dismissing imediatelly):

[image: bug]

The bug:

- Doesn't happen in my development env;
- Doesn't happen in Firefox
- Doesn't happen in other pages where there are identical forms, with data-remote="true" submission, and data-confirm on the submit button.
- Doesn't happen in other 4 different macbooks using Chrome as well!
- DOES happen in my production env, on my machine, EVEN on private tab;

This is so puzzling because since it happens only on my machine, but even on a private tab, it can't be an extension, but I simply cannot reproduce this bug on any other machine, browser, or even in my own machine in the development env.

It's so weird that even starting rails with `RAILS_ENV=production`, so that I get all the assets just like they are in production, the bug doesn't happen.

Attaching a debugger to the mouse.click using Chrome devtools (sources tab) makes the bug go away (the debugger fires as soon as I click the button, I resume code, and the confirm window appears only once).

I have no clue how to debug this weird behavior. Could just let it go, but I fear it will come back to bite me later on, so I need to understand why this is happening on my machine.

There was an old bug in the jquery-ujs lib (https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/384) but it was fixed years ago and I'm on the latest version of the lib (https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/commit/9e805c90c8cfc57b39967052e1e9013ccb318cf8), which even has a safe mechanism that errors out if it's included more than once, and there's no errors in the console (I'm sure the lib is only included once).

Not using turbolinks.

**UPDATE 1**

I added a gif of the bug above.

Also, I imported `jquery-ujs` manually (copy and paste from https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/commit/9e805c90c8cfc57b39967052e1e9013ccb318cf8) and edited the `confirm` method:

```
confirm: function(message) {
      console.trace();
      return confirm(message);
    },
```

In dev tools, I confirm the trace appears only once even in production when the bug happens, and here's the stack trace:

[image]

Comment: 1) Is it possible for us to see it live? 2) If no, can you capture it with video or screenshot? Just to know what we talk about. 3) I think it is ok to edit jquery-ujs in order to debug it

Comment: @lucifer63 I added a gif to the question. Also, followed your tip #3 and edited jquery-ujs manually, but weirdly `console.trace()` shows `confirm()` is being invoked only once, even tough the bug persists.

Comment: Pop Up Blocker?

Comment: @epascarello Nope, it's Chrome 75 with no extensions (icognito tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out the culprit: Facebook pixel code JS.

Like I said, this was a hard one to debug. Any debugger you attached to window.confirm() just made the bug disappear (window.confirm then just appeared once, as expected). Also, I couldn't reproduce it in development, even with `RAILS_ENV=production`.

So how did I found out? **I noticed in the dev tools that every time I clicked that blue submit button, a request was being made to facebook server initiated by fbevents.js**. That's facebook pixel code.

Just tried a deploy without that script and ... FINALLY, problem is over.

Damn you fbevents.js

Comment: So, FB just redefined `confirm` function?

Answer (score 1):

1) Refresh the page
2) Run this in your Developer console (F12): `window.confirm = function() { debugger; }`
3) Click the submit button and debug from there.

Inspecting the callstack may give you some insight as to what's happening.

Comment: thanks for the tip. Using it, I can confirm the function is being invoked only once. Please take a look at the updated question for extra info (UPDATE 1)